# How can I solve error occurred while proxying request? RedwoodJS

Tags: redwoodjs

I'm following [RedwoodJS Tutorial - Getting Dynamic](https://redwoodjs.com/docs/tutorial/chapter2/getting-dynamic) and there's a proxy error when requesting `localhost:8910/posts`

```
api | API listening on http://localhost:8911/
api | GraphQL endpoint at /graphql
api | 11:14:25  Server listening at http://[::]:8911
web | <e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:8910/graphql to http://[::1]:8911/ [ENETUNREACH] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your node and yarn versions match the [prerequisites](https://redwoodjs.com/docs/tutorial/chapter1/prerequisites#nodejs-and-yarn-versions);

```
node: ">=14.19 <=16.x"
yarn: ">=1.15"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `RWJS_DEV_API_URL="http://localhost"` to your environment variable; either by running `RWJS_DEV_API_URL=“http://localhost” yarn rw dev` or as a new line to your .env file